# putting some WPF windows in DLL

Tags: wpf, dll, window

I have a WPF project, and there is one dialog that I will re-use in different applications.  I want to put it in its own DLL, but when I use the New Project wizard in Visual Studio 2008 it only lets me create WinForm C# DLLs.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to create a WPF Custom Control Library project.

Answer (score 1):

To add to this, this particular project does not actually show up unless you specifically choose **Classic Desktop** projects.

[image: Image of Visual Studio project window with Classic Desktop type selected.]